# How to NOT overwrite current DateFile with log4js

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

Hello I have following log4js configuration:

```
const defaultPath = './logs/notif.log'
const defaultFormat = '"%d{yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS}","%p","%x{user}","%m"'

module.exports = (level = 'debug', path = defaultPath, format = defaultFormat, compress = true) => {
  const log4js = require('log4js')
  const user = require('os').userInfo().username

  const layout = {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: format,
    tokens: {
      user: user,
    },
  }

  log4js.configure({
    appenders: {
      stdout: {
        type: 'stdout',
        layout: layout,
      },
      file: {
        type: 'dateFile',
        filename: path,
        pattern: '.yyyyMMdd',
        compress: compress,
        layout: layout,
      },
      logFilter: {
        type: 'logLevelFilter',
        appender: 'file',
        level: 'info',
      },
    },
    categories: {
      default: {
        appenders: ['stdout', 'logFilter'],
        level: level,
      },
    },
  })
  return log4js.getLogger()
}
```

My problem is that when I restart the program it will delete the content from the DateFile and  start "freshly" over.

**Is it possible with the current setup, when the app restarts, to append to the DateFile until its rolled over?**

It's really hard to google because 90% matches are for log4j and not for log4js. Kudo's to the name giver!